# center div using margin

Tags: html, css

i m trying to center a div(only horizontal) using the following css

```
.body_div 
{

  width: 900px;
  margin-left:  auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background-color: #f8f3ed;
}
```

and it does it work in chrome and ff but not in ie

take a look [here](http://122.176.89.242/leosite)

eventually i used the same code in another site too and it worked well in ie too

now a hell lot another problem...
the borders around the #courses and #call are not shown in ie...
thanks

Answer (score 2):

Remove the comment before the DOCTYPE. That places IE in [quirks mode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html) where it doesn't supports all standards.

---

These are currently the top lines of your site:

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
--> 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Change them to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Comment: like this <DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

Comment: omg wihtout the comment(!) it wont work...<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
thats the right answer...

Comment: You go out for lunch and people start editing your answers... (Thanks, @thirtydot :-)

Answer (score -2):

Use a single margin setting:

`margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: You might want to use Firebug to ensure that you don't have some other CSS rule that's taking precedence over the margin setting on your `.body_div`. Also, if that div is nested in another object whose width is constrained, you'll be centering within that object (not the window). Can you post the general structure of your DOM?

Comment: check this simple thing in ff and ie... http://122.176.89.242/leosite/index2.html

Comment: it has to do something with the output in which format because i now changed it to jsp and it just worked fine... 122.176.89.242/leosite/index2.jsp where the encoding is in <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> how can change simple html page encoding...

Comment: You might want to try specifying `width: 100%;` for `body, html`.

Comment: See RoToRa's link. Thanks, downvoters. I guess the SO expectations have risen since I last visited. I didn't think my answer and subsequent comments were that bad.